# How to draw "guidelines" between elements of nested Word lists?

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word allows you to make nested lists:

```
- Fruit
    - Apples
    - Oranges
      - Sweet
        - Spain
        - Greece
      - Sour
```

If you have many long and nested lists, reading the list properly becomes confusing fast. Therefore, is it possible to, just like in Windows Explorer, get "guiding lines" between  elements? To make myself clear, here's some badass ASCII art to show what I mean:

```
Fruit
|-- Apples
|-- Oranges
    |-- Sweet
    |   |-- Spain
    |   |-- Greece
    |
    |-- Sour
```

I really need this, so any hack that would create something like this is appreciated :-)